# pandas equivalent of Stata collapse lastnm

Tags: pandas, stata

I am trying to replicate Stata's `collapse (lastnm)` function in pandas. Consider the following minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = (pd.DataFrame({"group": [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2],
                "period":[1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2],
                "value1": [2,np.NaN,7,8,np.NaN,1,5,4,6,np.NaN],
                "value2": [1,3,np.NaN, 8,np.NaN,1,5,4,6,np.NaN]}))
```

Desired output:

```
collapsed_df = (pd.DataFrame({"group":[1,1,2,2],
                              "period":[1,2,1,2],
                              "value1":[2,8,5,6],
                              "value2":[3,8,5,6]}))
```

Basically something like:

```
collapsed_df = df.groupby(["group", "period"])["value1","value2"].last()
```

But this will give me missing values if the last value was indeed missing. What I would like is to have something like

```
collapsed_df = df.groupby(["group", "period"])["value1","value2"].lastnm()
```

Update: I havent realized that pandas by default keep the last non-missing value, so problem is solved.

Comment: put .dropna before your .groupby

Comment: fair enough but this only works with one column. I changed the example but also noted that pandas default behavoiur is actually to return the last non-missing value

Comment: have updated my answer in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just groupby and pandas will ignore missing values. The below will get you the desired result:

```
df.groupby(["group", "period"], as_index=False).last()
```

Gives:

```
   group  period  value1  value2
0      1       1     2.0     3.0
1      1       2     8.0     8.0
2      2       1     5.0     5.0
3      2       2     6.0     6.0
```